# How to retrieve the result of a periodic Celery task?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am using `Celery 3.1` together with `djcelery` and the database result backend.

I have got a few periodic tasks that run every 24h.

I want to retrieve the result of one of those tasks from various places in the project (different applications) but I don't know how to get the right entry from the many objects in `TaskMeta.objects.all()` as I don't have the task_id.

Is there a way to ask something like: "I want the result of the last entry corresponding to the execution of the periodic task `<name_of_function>`."?

Comment: you should find an answer here: https://github.com/celery/django-celery-results/issues/7